# How to efficiently instance Eq for a type class

Tags: haskell

I made the following class to convert between different temperature types:

```
data Temp = Kelvin Float | Celsius Float |Fahrenheit Float deriving Show

conversionKelvin:: Temp -> Temp
conversionKelvin (Celsius x) = Kelvin (x + 273.15)
conversionKelvin (Fahrenheit x) = Kelvin((x - 32) * 5/9 + 273.15)
conversionKelvin (Kelvin x) = Kelvin x

conversionCelsius:: Temp -> Temp
conversionCelsius (Kelvin x) = Celsius (x - 273.15)
conversionCelsius (Fahrenheit x) = Celsius((x - 32) * 5/9)
conversionCelsius (Celsius x) = Celsius x

conversionFahrenheit:: Temp -> Temp
conversionFahrenheit (Celsius x) = Fahrenheit (x * 9/5 + 32)
conversionFahrenheit (Kelvin x) = Fahrenheit((x - 273.15)*9/5 + 32)
conversionFahrenheit (Fahrenheit x) = Fahrenheit x
```

So far all's good, however I want to implement the instance Eq and Ord. I thought about converting each type to celsius and then see which is bigger, but I can't manage to get past the compiler.
Any help?

Edit: Here's my attempt at instancing Eq:

```
instance Eq Temp where
    a == b = conversionCelsius(a) == conversionCelsius(b)
```

It compiles but it makes haskell enter some kind of loop (doesn't print the output)

Comment: How did you implmement the `instance Eq`? Beware that floating-point calculations often have rounding errors, so two values can be equal "by accident" if they are close to each other and vice versa.

Comment: You also need to convert the `Kelvin` to `Kelvin`, etc.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem , noted and updated

Comment: One way to avoid issues with rounding is to replace the fixed-precision `Float` with an arbitrary-precision exact `Rational` (from `Data.Ratio`), then use `fromRational` to convert to fixed precision at the end. Otherwise, for example, converting a temperature from Celsius to Fahrenheit and back will not necessarily produce values that will compare equal with `(==)`: `let { x = 1 :: Rational; } in (x, ((x * 9/5 + 32.0) - 32.0) * 5/9)` produces exactly equal values `(1 % 1, 1 % 1)`, but using `Float` / `Double` instead produces unequal values `(1.0,0.9999996)` / `(1.0,0.9999999999999984)`.

Comment: Consider storing *every* temperature in the same unit (probably Kelvin), and only convert to/from the other units for display purposes. You'll probably be working *with* temperatures more than you need to create or display them, and if everything is normalized to Kelvin right away, `Eq` and `Ord` are trivial and derivable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you first need to convert `Kelvin` to `Kelvin` as well, etc.:

```
conversionKelvin:: Temp -> Temp
conversionKelvin (Celsius x) = Kelvin (x + 273.15)
conversionKelvin (Fahrenheit x) = Kelvin((x - 32) * 5/9 + 273.15)
conversionKelvin k@(Kelvin _) = k
```

As for the `Eq` instance, you can indeed first convert the two temperatures to the same unit (regardless what that unit is), and then check if these are equal:

```
instance Eq Temp where
    a == b | ~(Kelvin ka) <- conversionKelvin a, ~(Kelvin kb) <- conversionKelvin b = ka == kb
```

That being said, calculations with `Float`s often result in *rounding errors*. This thus means that two `Temp`s that *are* the same can be considered different, and two `Temp`s that are slightly different can be considered the same.

You can also implement a function `toKelvin :: Temp -> Float`, since it is clear what unit of the result is:

```
toKelvin :: Temp -> Float
toKelvin (Celsius x) = x + 273.15
toKelvin (Fahrenheit x) = (x - 32) * 5/9 + 273.15
toKelvin (Kelvin k) = k
```

and then use:

```
instance Eq Temp where
    a == b = toKelvin a == toKelvin kb
```

Answer (score 6):

This leads to infinite recursion

```
instance Eq Temp where
    a == b = conversionCelsius(a) == conversionCelsius(b)
```

This is because the comparison `a == b` is between two `Temp`s, and the comparison `conversionCelsius(a) == conversionCelsius(b)` is *again* between two `Temp`s, so we recurse forever.

To stop the recursion, you need to have at least a base case, where the comparison between `Temp`s is done by comparing `Float`s. A possible solution is the following one.

```
instance Eq Temp where
    Celsius x == Celsius y = x == y
    a         == b         = conversionCelsius a == conversionCelsius b
```

This will compare Celsius temperatures directly, comparing their `Float` values. Other temperatures are instead converted to Celsuis before recursing. After we recurse, we will immediately find the base case, so the recursion ends.

Answer (score 0):

How about picking a normal form for your representation, deriving the `Eq` instance

```
type    Temp :: Type
newtype Temp = Celsius Float
  deriving
  newtype Eq
```

but then creating [pattern synonyms](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/pattern_synonyms.html?highlight=pattern%20synonyms) for different units

```
pattern Kelvin :: Float -> Temp
pattern Kelvin kelvin <- Celsius (celsiusToKelvin -> kelvin)
  where Kelvin kelvin =  Celsius (kelvinToCelsius kelvin)

pattern Fahrenheit :: Float -> Temp
pattern Fahrenheit fahrenheit <- Celsius (celsiusToFahrenheit -> fahrenheit)
  where Fahrenheit fahrenheit =  Celsius (fahrenheitToCelsius fahrenheit)
```